# Why Owl carousel not loading some time

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, knockout.js, owl-carousel

Here I am Populating slider information from Ajax and its working fine for some time after refresh page again I made ajax call and it do same but Slider doesn't load

```
            $.ajax({
            url: 'api/User/GetSportCategoryList',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function (e) {
                e.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic b3BiYW5kOm9wYmFuZA==")
            },
            type: "get",
            success: function (data) {
                gTournamentList = data.tournamentBannerList;
                console.log($(".tournament-list-slider-element").html()); //First time no html content.
                           var len = gTournamentList.length;
        var htmlstring = '' ;
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
            htmlstring += '<div class="item">' +
                '           <div class="headcol" style="cursor:pointer">' +
                '                <div class="headcolleft">' +
                '                    <div class="tourcol"> <img src ="'+gTournamentList[i].Image+'" height="100px" width="200px" alt="" >' +
                '                     </div>' +
                '                </div>' +
                '                <div class="headcolrig">' +
                '                    <div class="tourtxt">' + gTournamentList[i].TournamentName + '</div>' +
                '                </div>' +
                '              </div>' +
                '            </div>';
            }
        htmlstring += '';
        $(".tournament-list-slider-element").html(htmlstring);
        len = gTournamentList.length;
        var noOfElement = 0;
        switch (len) {
            case 1: noOfElement = 1;
                break;
            case 2: noOfElement = 2;
                break;
            case 3: noOfElement = 3;
                break;
            case 4: noOfElement = 4;
                break;
            default: noOfElement = 4;
        }

        $(".tournament-list-slider-element").owlCarousel({
            items: noOfElement, //10 items above 1000px browser width
            itemsDesktop: [1000, 3], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
            itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 3], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
            itemsTablet: [600, 2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
            itemsMobile: [320, 1] // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
        });
        // Custom Navigation Events
        $(".next3").click(function () {
            $(".tournament-list-slider-element").trigger('owl.next');
        })
        $(".prev3").click(function () {
            $(".tournament-list-slider-element").trigger('owl.prev');
        })

            }
```

First time work successfully after refresh page slider be come Empty. How to resolve? Please help.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that when the page loads, owl-carousel sometimes works, but not always? Or are you saying that after your page makes an AJAX call, owl-carousel stops working?

Do you have any console errors? What does the page look like when the slider is not working? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Consider Slider on Home.html page and after redirect to Contact.html page again i come to home.html page slider become empty. I try to reinit owl carousel but didn't find proper way to Reinit.  I have Uploaded Screenshot here         :->               Link : Working http://www.tourneypick.com/Upload/1.png                             Second Refresh not working http://www.tourneypick.com/Upload/2.png